# maven build downloads my projects from remote repository instead of my local hard drive

Tags: maven

I have added the below repository in my pom.xml, as I need Primefaces library.

```
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>prime-repo</id>
                    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
```

But once added when I run the build the build logs shows it downloads from the remote repository http://repository.primefaces.org instead of my local hard drive.. and have the below logs.

Please clarify.
Many thanks.

```
            [INFO] Scanning for projects...
            [INFO]                                                                         
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [INFO] Building xxx_presentation Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/business/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/data/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.pom
            Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.pom
            [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/common/my_common/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/common/my_common/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/common/business/my_common_business/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/com/jay/common/data/my_common_data/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

Comment: Do you really need that separate repository? Which artifact do you need which is not in maven central?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, I need primefaces-3.5.jar & cupertino-1.0.8.jar both are from primefaces and I get from repository http://repository.primefaces.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency of Maven attempts to connect to the remote repository can be configured by specifying the **updatePolicy** like explained in the [Maven Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories).

'Daily' is the default but you can configure it so that it fits your needs. In short it works like this (copied from the above mentioned Maven documentation):

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
      <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

**updatePolicy**: This element specifies how often updates should attempt to occur. Maven will compare the local POM's timestamp (stored in a repository's maven-metadata file) to the remote. The choices are: always, daily (default), interval:X (where X is an integer in minutes) or never.

Answer (score 0):

Adding repository to your pom.xml means maven will use it to download dependencies for the first time .Then maven will use local repo.
This is the default behavior

Comment: Thanks, it does not download every time when I run the build. But happens some times, may be once a day... Does it upload any of my files into this remote repository ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. Maven search artifacts in remote repository for the first time, and then download it to your local repository (hidden directory /.m2). Next time you do a build maven will take the local copy.

offtopic: if you want to use propietary artifacts or own made artifacts, then I recommend you to use Nexus maven repository manager.